# Getting Daylight Savings Time Start and End in NodaTime

Tags: c#, date, dst, nodatime

How can I get the starting and ending dates for Daylight Savings Time using Noda Time?
The function below accomplishes this task but it is horribly unwieldy and is begging for a simpler solution.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the start and end of daylight savings time in a given time zone
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tz">The time zone in question</param>
/// <returns>A tuple indicating the start and end of DST</returns>
/// <remarks>Assumes this zone has daylight savings time</remarks>
private Tuple<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime> GetZoneStartAndEnd(DateTimeZone tz)
{
    int thisYear = TimeUtils.SystemLocalDateTime.Year; // Get the year of the current LocalDateTime

    // Get January 1, midnight, of this year and next year.
    var yearStart = new LocalDateTime(thisYear, 1, 1, 0, 0).InZoneLeniently(tz).ToInstant();
    var yearEnd = new LocalDateTime(thisYear + 1, 1, 1, 0, 0).InZoneLeniently(tz).ToInstant();

    // Get the intervals that we experience in this year
    var intervals = tz.GetZoneIntervals(yearStart, yearEnd).ToArray();

    // Assuming we are in a US-like daylight savings scheme,
    // we should see three intervals:
    // 1. The interval that January 1st sits in
    // 2. At some point, daylight savings will start.
    // 3. At some point, daylight savings will stop.
    if (intervals.Length == 1)
        throw new Exception("This time zone does not use daylight savings time");
    if (intervals.Length != 3)
        throw new Exception("The daylight savings scheme in this time zone is unexpected.");

    return new Tuple<LocalDateTime,LocalDateTime>(intervals[1].IsoLocalStart, intervals[1].IsoLocalEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's not a single built-in function that I am aware of, but the data is all there, so you can certainly create your own.

You're on the right track with what you've shown, but there are a few things to consider:

- Normally people are interested in the *end* points of the intervals.  By returning the start and stop of only the middle interval, you are likely getting values different than you expect.  For example, if you use one of the US time zones, such as `"America/Los_Angeles"`, your function returns the transitions as  `3/9/2014 3:00:00 AM` and `11/2/2014 2:00:00 AM`, where you are probably expecting 2:00 AM for both.
- Time zones south of the equator that use DST will start it towards the end of the year, and end it towards the beginning of the next year.  So sometimes the items in the tuple might be reversed from what you expect them to be.
- There are quite a lot of time zones that don't use daylight saving time, so throwing an exception isn't the best idea.
- There are at least two time zones that presently have four transitions in a single year ([`"Africa/Casablanca"`](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/morocco/casablanca?year=2014) and [`"Africa/Cairo"`](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/egypt/cairo?year=2014)) - having a "break" in their DST periods for Ramadan.  And occasionally, there are non-DST-related transitions, such as when [Samoa changed its standard offset in 2011](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/samoa-dateline.html), which gave it *three* transitions in a single year.

Taking all of this into account, it would seem better to return a list of single transition points, rather than a tuple of pairs of transitions.

Also, this is minor, but it would be better form to not bind the method to the system clock at all.  The year can easily be passed by parameter.  Then you can use this method for non-current years if necessary.

```
public IEnumerable<LocalDateTime> GetDaylightSavingTransitions(DateTimeZone timeZone, int year)
{
    var yearStart = new LocalDateTime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0).InZoneLeniently(timeZone).ToInstant();
    var yearEnd = new LocalDateTime(year + 1, 1, 1, 0, 0).InZoneLeniently(timeZone).ToInstant();
    var intervals = timeZone.GetZoneIntervals(yearStart, yearEnd);

    return intervals.Select(x => x.IsoLocalEnd).Where(x => x.Year == year);
}
```

Also note at the end, it's important to filter just the values that are in the current year because the intervals may very well extend into the following year, or go on indefinitely.

Comment: Would this be the correct basis for a simple bool IsDaylightSavings(DateTimeZone timeZone, Instant instant) method, or is there a better way?

Comment: What does your method do? Noda Time's documentation isn't easy to understand. I don't get what `IsoLocalEnd` is and how it can be used to get the DST transition times.

Comment: @Azimuth - By the docs, a `ZoneInterval` *"represents a range of time for which a particular Offset applies,"* and its [`IsoLocalEnd`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/?topic=html/P_NodaTime_TimeZones_ZoneInterval_IsoLocalEnd.htm) property *"returns the local start time of the interval, as `LocalDateTime` in the ISO calendar. This does not include any daylight saving"*.  These are half-open intervals, so this gives us the local time that the transition occurs.

Comment: For example, in the USA, we just had the fall-back transition, where we commonly say "at 2:00 local time, go back to 1:00 local time".  In reality, it's "as the clocks *approach* 2:00".  If you're actually *at* 2:00, then the transition had already occurred an hour earlier.  But it's still the 2:00 time we are interested in when we ask for the transition. Thus, we want the `IsoLocalEnd` value of the zone interval.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet code also help you to check a time is in daylightsavingstime or not

```
public static bool IsDaylightSavingsTime(this DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset)
        {
            var timezone = "Europe/London"; //https://nodatime.org/TimeZones
            ZonedDateTime timeInZone = dateTimeOffset.DateTime.InZone(timezone);
            var instant = timeInZone.ToInstant();
            var zoneInterval = timeInZone.Zone.GetZoneInterval(instant);
            return zoneInterval.Savings != Offset.Zero;
        }
```

how to use it

```
var testDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var isDst = testDate.IsDaylightSavingsTime();
```

Depend on your situation, you can modify it a bit

Comment: `".InZone(timezone)"` doesn't seem to compile. 

`ZonedDateTime timeInZone = dateTimeOffset.DateTime.InZone(timezone);`

Comment: U need using NodaTime;