# Calculate duration (amount to spring forward/fall back) at DST transitions boundaries

Tags: c#, date, dst, nodatime

From this great answer, I am able to determine daylight saving transitions dates:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378695/1159939

In addition of those dates, I need to know if the clock is going to increase or decrease and by what amount (is it always an hour?).

For example, in time zone US/Pacific, when the local clock reaches 2020-03-08T02:00:00, I need to somehow get value +1h. When the clock reaches 2020-11-01T02:00:00, I need to get value -1h.

In NodaTime, there is a Offset.Savings value that is +0 or +1. Now sure how I can use that.

**--Update1:**
I am building a scheduler. I need to give the user more control over how jobs are executed when a scheduled job is to occur during the 1-hour savings period.

I am thinking for having the following settings the user can select:

[x] Run missed jobs when clocks spring forward.

[x] Re-run jobs when clocks fall back.

For example, let's say a job is scheduled to run at 2020-03-08T02:15:00 US/Pacific. This local time does not exist. If the user ticks off the "Run missed jobs when clocks spring forward" checkbox, the job will be executed at 3:15AM, otherwise, the job will be skipped.

For example, let's say a job is scheduled to run at 2020-11-01T01:45:00 US/Pacific. This local time will occur twice. If the user ticks off the "Re-run jobs when clocks fall back", the job will be executed twice, otherwise, it will be executed once.

In order to make the calculations above, I need to know the day light saving transition dates which I got from the post mentioned previously. I also need to know which direction the clocks will change and by how much (e.g.: 1h).

**--Update2:**

After giving it more thought, I think I need a list of time zone transitions that contains the following data:

```
2020-03-08 02:00:00 US/Eastern | 2020-03-08 07:00:00 UAT (01:00:00)
2020-11-01 02:00:00 US/Eastern | 2020-11-01 06:00:00 UAT (-01:00:00)
```

Below is the code that I am using to generate this data. Not sure if this will work in all cases. In order to calculate time change, I am using the difference between the start of the next zone interval and the end of the current zone interval.

```
using NodaTime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string timeZoneId = "US/Eastern";
            DateTimeZone? timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(timeZoneId);

            if (timeZone is null)
                throw new Exception($"Cannot find time zone '{timeZoneId}'.");

            int year = 2020;

            var daylightSavingTransitions = GetDaylightSavingTransitions(timeZone, year);

            foreach (var daylightSavingTransition in daylightSavingTransitions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(daylightSavingTransition);
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Get points in time when a daylight saving time transitions occur.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="timeZone">Time zone of the local clock.</param>
            /// <param name="year">The year to find transitions.</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            static IEnumerable<DaylightSavingTransition> GetDaylightSavingTransitions(DateTimeZone timeZone, int year)
            {
                var yearStart = new LocalDateTime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0).InZoneLeniently(timeZone).ToInstant();
                var yearEnd = new LocalDateTime(year + 1, 1, 1, 0, 0).InZoneLeniently(timeZone).ToInstant();

                LinkedList<NodaTime.TimeZones.ZoneInterval> zoneIntervals = new LinkedList<NodaTime.TimeZones.ZoneInterval>(timeZone.GetZoneIntervals(yearStart, yearEnd));
                LinkedListNode<NodaTime.TimeZones.ZoneInterval>? currentNode = zoneIntervals.First;

                while (currentNode is { })
                {
                    if (currentNode.Next is null)
                        break;

                    //Time change is the difference between the start of the next zone interval and the end of the current zone interval.
                    Period timeChangePeriod = currentNode.Next.Value.IsoLocalStart - currentNode.Value.IsoLocalEnd;
                    TimeSpan timeChange = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(timeChangePeriod.Hours), Convert.ToInt32(timeChangePeriod.Minutes), Convert.ToInt32(timeChangePeriod.Seconds));
                    DaylightSavingTransition daylightSavingTransition = new DaylightSavingTransition(timeZone.Id, currentNode.Value.IsoLocalEnd.ToDateTimeUnspecified(), currentNode.Value.End.ToDateTimeUtc(), timeChange);
                    yield return daylightSavingTransition;

                    currentNode = currentNode.Next;
                }
            }
        }
    }



    public class DaylightSavingTransition
    {
        public DaylightSavingTransition(string timeZoneId, DateTime transitionLocalDate, DateTime transitionUtcDate, TimeSpan timeChange)
        {
            TimeZoneId = timeZoneId;
            TransitionLocalDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(transitionLocalDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            TransitionUtcDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(transitionUtcDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            TimeChange = timeChange;
        }

        public string TimeZoneId { get; }
        public DateTime TransitionLocalDate { get; }
        public DateTime TransitionUtcDate { get; }
        public TimeSpan TimeChange { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// For fall back transition, used to determine if date is in the duplicated time period.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="utcDateTime">Point in time to test if it is inside the repeating time period.</param>
        public bool IsRepeatingDateTime(DateTime utcDateTime)
        {
            if (utcDateTime >= TransitionUtcDate && utcDateTime < TransitionUtcDate.Add(TimeChange.Duration()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{TransitionLocalDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")} {TimeZoneId} | {TransitionUtcDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")} UAT ({TimeChange})";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "when the clock reaches". What is the *shape* of the code you want to write? (If it's a method, what would that method signature be like?) I suspect you're interested in the `ZoneInterval` and `ZoneLocalMapping` types, but I can't really give a concrete example in code without knowing what you're expecting.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you Jon. I've updated the main post with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're *really* looking for is [`DateTimeZone.MapLocal(LocalDateTime)`](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.DateTimeZone.html#NodaTime_DateTimeZone_MapLocal_NodaTime_LocalDateTime_). That returns a [`ZoneLocalMapping`](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.ZoneLocalMapping.html) which tells you how a local date/time is mapped into the specified time zone. The important properties are:

- `Count`

  - 0 if the date/time is skipped
  - 1 if it's mapped unambiguously
  - 2 if it's mapped ambiguously
- `EarlyInterval` and `LateInterval` which are the `ZoneInterval` values for before/after any transition around the specified `LocalDateTime` (or the same `ZoneInterval` if the value isn't in a transition)

`ZoneInterval` contains a `WallOffset` which is the overall UTC offset during that zone interval. I'd strongly recommend using that rather than `Savings`, in order to cope with transitions which *aren't* daylight saving transitions (e.g. if the standard time for a zone changes).

You should be able to use that information to determine when to run things.

You could also use [`DateTimeZone.ResolveLocal(LocalDateTime, ZoneLocalMappingResolver)`](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.DateTimeZone.html#NodaTime_DateTimeZone_ResolveLocal_NodaTime_LocalDateTime_NodaTime_TimeZones_ZoneLocalMappingResolver_) where you'd build your own resolver (for handling skipped/ambiguous times) based on what the user has selected.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet. I've updated my original post with what I think I need. But not sure if what I am doing is going to work in all cases. If you have time, please let me know if it will work or if there is a better solution. Really appreciate your time and thank you for your work on Noda Time.

Comment: @Sandy: Your `DaylightSavingTransition` class really duplicates a lot of the information in `ZoneInterval`. I would expect it to be simpler just to use `ZoneInterval`. You should use the difference in `WallOffset` properties between two `ZoneInterval` values to determine how much the clocks change - that's *definitely* better than taking a period. If you want to keep your `DaylightSavingTransition` class (which is inaccurately named as there are transitions which *aren't* due to daylight savings, btw) I would suggest you just give that two `ZoneInterval` fields for "before" and "after".

Comment: @Sandy: You can then compute the properties you need from that. I would suggest sticking to Noda Time types as far as you possibly can though, instead of exposing `DateTime` values.

Comment: I have renamed classes and refactored my code to contain a before & after ZoneInterval. I'm unable to use Noda Time types through my code because I need to move the data from Noda Time types to DateTime and TimeSpan in my DTOs. I use ToDateTimeUtc() on ZoneInterval Start and End. I use ToTimeSpan() on WallOffset.  I don't think the following issue is related to using BCL types, but when I now calculate local time zone end date, I am off by 1 hour for start DST periods. For example, I get 2020-03-08T03:00:00 instead of 2020-03-08T02:00:00 for Canada/Eastern. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @Sandy: I would recommend using the Noda Time types for your DTOs :) Anyway, please ask a new question with a [mcve] for the Canada/Eastern aspect - I don't want to start effectively trying to debug in a comment thread.